# Different versions of django

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I have just moved my django application to another server, which I have configured a long time ago, so I'm not really sure what's installed and configured. When running the application, I started getting weird errors, which pointed to running an old version of django. Hence, I decided to check the version.

First, I ran:

```
python -c "import django; print(django.get_version())"
```

which showed version **1.3.1**. So then I did

```
sudo easy_install --upgrade django
```

which ran fine, but when running the first command again, it still shows **1.3.1**, so I decided to do:

```
django-admin.py version
```

and this returned **1.6.5**. Therefore, I assume that I have installed the latest django version, but for some reason python is using **1.3.1**.

**How can I get python to use the latest version of django?**

Comment: what OS are you using?

Comment: I'm running Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS.

Comment: what do you get if you `import django` and run `django.__file__`

Comment: '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/__init__.pyc'

Comment: and in the python shell `django.get_version()
` shows 1.3.1 also?`

Comment: when it installed the package where did the line `Installed ...` show the package was installed?

Comment: What was the output for `sudo easy_install --upgrade django`?

Comment: Right now it's Searching for django
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/
Best match: Django 1.6.5
Processing Django-1.6.5-py2.7.egg
Django 1.6.5 is already the active version in easy-install.pth
Installing django-admin.py script to /usr/local/bin

Using /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.6.5-py2.7.egg
Processing dependencies for django
Finished processing dependencies for django

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly do not use `easy_install` but `pip`:

```
easy install pip
```

Try to install/update from `pip`:

```
pip install django --upgrade
```

If it fails, try to uninstall and after réinstall:

```
pip uninstall django
```

Be careful if you've installed django with Ubuntu's `apt-get`. It's a bad thing to mix system and python installers. Uninstall from `apt-get` if it's the case:

```
apt-get remove python-django
```

Comment: Good tip about installing from apt-get, +1.